# Why does my PyQGIS standalone script not work

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I wrote a pyqgis script that should iterate over a folder with xyz files, check if the bouding box overlaps with a polygon in my QGIS project and if yes, it should copy the file into a new folder.

I don't get an error message but nothing happens either. My output Folder remains empty. I just don't see the problem. Can someone please help me find the error, I've already spent too much time on this.

```
def moveFiles(self):
    mask = self.getBoundingBox() #BoundingBox of polygon layer
    inputDir = self.dlg.input_folder.text() #directory of xyz files - "Users/denni/Desktop/xyz_data"
    outDir = self.dlg.output_folder.text()  #output directory - "C:/Users/denni/Desktop/output/"
    crs = "EPSG:25832"

    for file in glob.glob("*.xyz"):
        uri = "file:///" + inputDir +"/"+ file + "?type=csv&delimiter=%s&crs=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (" ", crs, "field_1", "field_2")
        name = file.replace('.xyz', '')
        lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, "delimitedtext")
        lyr.selectAll()
        lyr.boundingBoxOfSelected()
        outputPath = outDir + file
        self.iface.addVectorLayer(file)

        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMinimum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMinimum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ')
        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMaximum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMinimum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ')
        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMaximum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMaximum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ')
        if mask.xMinimum() <= lyr.xMinimum() <= mask.xMaximum() and mask.yMinimum() <= lyr.yMaximum() <= mask.yMaximum():
            QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(lyr, outputPath, 'utf-8', lyr.crs(), "CSV", layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ')
```

I'm using QGIS 3.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type of `layerOptions` should be `list` of strings, not just `string`. Try to change `layerOptions='GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ'` as `layerOptions=['GEOMETRY=AS_XYZ']`.

`writeAsVectorFormat` documentation:

> `writeAsVectorFormat(..., layerOptions: Iterable[str] = [], ...)`

Comment: yes that was the issue, thanks for that :)

Comment: The next error message is strange again. Its telling me ''QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'xMinimum"

But `mask = self.getBoundingBox()` gets the bounding box as a QgsRectangle and according to the documentation (https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRectangle.html#a7fe11d0cd4fb7146dca5516c3eb03347) I can access the xMinimum with `xMinimum()`. Any ideas what the problem here is?

Comment: The error is about `lyr.xMinimum()`, not `mask.xMinimum`.

Comment: Use `extent = lyr.extent()`, then `if mask.xMinimum() <= extent.xMinimum()`.

Comment: That solved the 2nd problem, thank you very much! There was also a 3rd problem that I had to use elif instead of if. But now it finally works